# I need help linking my external files on my websites server

Tags: html, css

Recently re-did all the files to my website, and uploaded them to the 000webhost server they're located on. It's just some basic HTML but is heavily reliant on the CSS to make it look good. So when I checked it out to see that it didn't work, I realized not only did the javascript not work but the CSS too. I think it might be an error in my code, seeing as all the other files work fine. Any help would be appreciated.

I've tried redirecting the file paths, adding the head tags, deleting and re-adding the file to the server, and waiting to see if it was a server issue.

Here is the first couple of lines to my index HTML file:

```
<html>
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/amistufffavicon.ico">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<script src="functions.js"></script>
```

I really just want to make the HTML pages look good, and an explanation in case it ever happens again I know what to do.

Comment: You can use code sample (the icon with {}) to insert code snippets. You are also missing some peace of information in your question. In order to get a good answer, you will need to provide your files structure.

Answer (score 0):

first, use the {} logo on the top of the text editor to make your code show up. all you have to do is highlight your code, then click the {} button and it will format it for you.

your CSS and JS code actually looks like the HTML tags for these imports.

One bit of advice, if you have issues making several files work, just write everything in your HTML file

instead of

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="functions.js"></script>
```

just do this:

```
<html>

<style>
/*write style here*/
</style>

<script>
//write script here
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help with the editor and all the tips, but is there a way I could make the stylesheet linkable? Because it still doesn't work for some reason. The only problem with your method of writing the CSS in the style tags is that I would have to go through and edit all the HTML pages if I wanted to make a change to all of the pages.

Comment: Got the editor working! But not the error. Any help, again, is appreciated